# Calculate average hits with timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

On my website I use timestamps to track my users average length of time on my site. Each unique IP is logged with a "time entered" and a "time exited" record (updated using AJAX). With this I've been able to calculate the average length of time my users spend on my site.

However, I want to be able to calculate the average hits per day, week and month as well. I'm certain the timestamps could be used to achieve this, but I don't know how to go about solving the problem in PHP and MySQL. I've read on other websites that MySQL has some functions that can work out averages, but I don't know how to extract the timestamps for each day/week/month so wouldn't even be able to pass any data to said function(s).

I could make a table with "start" and "end" timestamps for every single day/week/month, and extract values in between using a loop/associative array, but that method seems over the top and verbose and would take a very long time. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

My table structure currently is:

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| start          | end            | unique_id      | id             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1358789867     | 1358789872     | (hash here)    | 65             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1358789966     | 1358789972     | (hash here)    | 66             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1358789998     | 1358790003     | (hash here)    | 67             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us the table columns and some rows.

Comment: How are you formatting the timestamp? php has `strtotime()` and `date_parse()` to get you what you want with almost any timestamp, especially if it's in a MySQL table. As far as building relationships in the database between tables, you're just going to need to start fiddling until you get it right, and be mindful of performance based selectors with heavy queries.

Comment: Do sessions last longer than the single day. E.g. is start and end always on the same day or can this be different days? Can a session be even longer than a single day (more than 24 hours)?

Comment: @hakre Technically yes. `start` and `end` are both set to the current timestamp via PHP when a user enters the site (to prevent null values in `end` if a user crashes while on my site). I use JavaScript to call PHP (AJAX) when the window exit event is fired to update the `end` record with the current timestamp, giving a relatively accurate time on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the average hits per day, you can just use the start timestamp.  However, the exact syntax depends on whether you are using `timestamp` or `unix_timestamp`.  For the first:

```
select date(timestamp_start), count(*)
from t
group by date(timestamp_start)
```

For `unix_timestamp`:

```
select date(from_timestamp(timestamp_start)), count(*)
from t
group by date(from_timestamp(timestamp_start))
```

This does the grouping by day, represented as a `date`.  Once you have it in that format, other functions, such as `year()`, month()`and`date_format()` can be used for the other time periods.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I'm having trouble implementing what you've given me (I'm very novice with MySQL). By any chance would you know a PHP method to achieve this? I have all the 'start' rows extracted to an array but cannot proceed. Regards, George.

Comment: @GeorgeAnthony . . . You should do the work in SQL, not in an array in PHP.  Just run the right SQL statement and read the results back.